# ajax with database query and show/hide table rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

I am building a simple website for a project. One of my page do MySQL database query and output all contents to a html table, I then use a filter enable uses to show/hide certain rows.
This strategy works well when deal with hundreds of rows, but when dealing with thousands of rows, there is a significant delay when people clicking the link. I thought might be I could add some Ajax, display a 'loading/querying' information when the query didn't finished.

A sample webpage: http://epigenome.wustl.edu/TE_Methylation/browse.php

When people go to that link, before database finished query, I want to display a 'loading' message, and also when people choose to hide several rows, before the Javascript finished hide the corresponding rows, also display a 'loading' information.
(The example page above didn't have this issue because there are only 900 rows, while I am working on a dataset with 10000+ rows)

Did anyone have some suggestions on how to achieve this? many thanks :)

Comment: why not add pagination?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting pagination. I just feel probably a lot of code are needed to be added for this feature. The delay is like 3-4 seconds, so a little didn't want to implement that. Thanks again.

Comment: besides pagination, I recommend [Google visualization table](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table). I've used it in projects similar to yours. It comes with sorting, filtering, etc, and is quite easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

When working with a large amount of data, you want to try and filter as much of that data before you send it to the client. Imagine that your viewer is on a mobile device or limited connection speed. This data will take even longer to transfer.

What I would do in your case, is set up an ajax service that responds with a json list of results for a given filter / criteria. I would then limit the response to a page or range as was stated in comments.

So, filter your results in your MySQL query using parameters provided via an Ajax request.

For example (a load more example)

```
var dataService = function() {
    this.Loaded = 0,
    this.Limit = 20,
    this.LoadMore = function() {
        $.getJSON("data_service.php", { FilterH1ES : true, Blah : true, Start : this.Loaded, Limit : this.Limit }, function(results) {
            // Append Rows to table
            // ...
        }
    }
}

// OnLoad call dataService.LoadMore();
```

Then in PHP, you would do the query filters for MySQL based on the parameters.

```
<?php
    $filters['H1ES'] = $_GET['FilterH1ES'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE /* Default Filter Here */";

    if ($filters['H1ES']) $sql .= " H1ES Filter";

    // ... run query and json_encode(result);
```

Code is not tested and my javascript is rusty.